# phpunit -coverage-html report path

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit, xdebug, xdebug-profiler

I have tried to execute phpunit with xdebug for code coverage as below,

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.22>phpunit -coverage-html /tmp C:\<unittest file pat>\TestRetainer.php
```

and it is giving output as follows,

```
PHPUnit 3.7.32 by Sebastian Bergmann.

....

Time: 36 ms, Memory: 5.75Mb

OK (4 tests, 12 assertions)

C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.22>
```

But i am unable to find the html version of report file.

I had gone through this url http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/phpunit-book.html#code-coverage-analysis. But i do not find any luck.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 13):

**For Linux, run command in the project root.**

```
./vendor/bin/phpunit --coverage-html reports/
```

This will create a folder named reports in your project root.

**For Windows:**

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.22>phpunit --coverage-html tmp C:\<unittest file pat>\TestRetainer.php
```

This will create a tmp folder inside php5.3.22, where your test report will generate.

Better if you keep reports inside your project root.

```
C:\wamp\htdocs\<project root> >phpunit --coverage-html tmp TestRetainer.php
```

Answer (score 10):

It looks like you're mixing Linux paths and windows paths:

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.22>phpunit --coverage-html /tmp C:\<unittest file pat>\TestRetainer.php
```

You're trying to write the coverage files to a folder called `/tmp`. On a Linux system this is a folder called `tmp` in the root of the drive. Change that to a Windows path (`C:\tmp` maybe?) and it should work.